# What sequences in $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ converge to the fixed point $0$ in $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$ while being fixed in $\lvert \cdot\rvert_3$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, p-adic-number-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose some uniformly continuous (under the 2-adic topology) function $f:\Bbb Z[\frac16]\to\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ converges under composition with itself to $0$ (in the 2-adic topology) for all inputs, and also satisfies $f(0)=0$.

Also let $f$ preserve the $3$-adic valuation, i.e. $\lvert f(x)\rvert_3=\lvert x\rvert_3$

> Is there some reason why such a function can approach $0$ only through some sequence terminating in $2^m3^n:m\to\infty$?

I can't show that some counterexample is a counterexample, but then my skills are sadly lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood all the conditions, but I think that the following function may be of interest here:
$$
f(x)=10x.
$$
Denoting the $n$-fold iterate by $f^{[n]}$.
Because $2\mid 10$ we have $$|f^{[n]}(x)|_2=(1/2)^n|x|_2$$ for all $x$. Therefore, for all $x$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{[n]}(x)=0$$ with respect to the $2$-adic metric. For the same reason $f$ is uniformly continuous w.r.t. the $2$-adic metric.

I'm uncertain what you mean by *can only approach zero through some sequence terminating in $2^m3^n$* means, but starting with the initial point $x=1$
the sequence $(f^{[n]}(x))_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ has no entries of the form $2^n3^m$.

Because $\gcd(3,10)=1$ we have $|f(x)|_3=|x|_3$ for all $x$.

Comment: Fully prepared to have misunderstood something, but you should describe the conditions more precisely.

Comment: Not misunderstood at all, thank-you, this appears to be perfect, in fact you've shown something stronger than what I asked for.  Really helpful to see the significance of picking $f(x)=2\cdot px$ where $\gcd(2p,3)=1$.

Comment: You mean *surjective*? My example $f$ is injective: $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$.

Comment: Hmm. That may prove to be a problem. May be not with your domain, but in $\Bbb{Z}_2$ surjectivity, uniform continuity and convergence to zero may be a difficult menage a trois due to compactness.

Comment: I was assuming we need to be in a subset of $\Bbb Q_2$ due to fractions $x/2^m$ in $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$. No counterexample for surjective $f$ is equivalent to the Collatz conjecture. If I could tempt you into a chat about it, I think you could really help me a lot but I also understand why you would not want to do that.

Comment: Wait a second! What's wrong with $f(x)=2x$. Because $1/2$ is in your domain that is surjective. With initial point $x=5$ we get the sequence $f^{[n]}(x)=5\cdot2^n\to0$.

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be a fairly obvious counterexample. I wasn't so confident about the implications of being uniformly continuous but it appears to be fairly straightforward.